# Executing exec-maven-plugin not part of normal build process, and without inheritance

Tags: java, maven, build, maven-3, maven-plugin

I am trying to execute a maven plugin outside of the normal build process, this is because it should be executed as part of a jenkins job only on merge to master. This is taken care of in the jenkins file. However, to ensure this, the plugin needs to not be triggered by running mvn clean install. The way I've done it now is put this plugin into pluginManagement and I call mvn exec:exec@goal when I wish to run the plugin.

This plugin should only be ran once, at parent level. I've set inherited to false, but the build still fails with this error message

```
The parameter 'executable' is missing or invalid
```

after executing successfully on parent level.
This is how my plugin is currently configured:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
           <inherited>false</inherited>
        <configuration>
           <param>${VID}</param>
           <param>${VKEY}</param>
           <param>${BUILD_NUMBER}</param>
           <executable>java</executable>
        </configuration>
           <executions>
              <execution>
                 <id>veracode</id>
                 <configuration>
                    <arguments>
                       <argument>-jar</argument>
                       <argument>${settings.localRepository}/com/veracode/vosp/api/wrappers/vosp-api-wrappers-java/20.7.7.0/vosp-api-wrappers-java-20.7.7.0.jar</argument>
                       <argument>-action</argument>
                       <argument>UploadAndScan</argument>
                       <argument>-vid</argument>
                       <argument>${VID}</argument>
                       <argument>-vkey</argument>
                       <argument>${VKEY}</argument>
                       <argument>-criticality</argument>
                       <argument>High</argument>
                       <argument>-createprofile</argument>
                       <argument>false</argument>
                       <argument>-createprofile</argument>
                       <argument>false</argument>
                       <argument>-version</argument>
                       <argument>${BUILD_NUMBER}</argument>
                       <argument>-appname</argument>
                       <argument>PULSE-DELIVERY</argument>
                       <argument>-sandboxname</argument>
                       <argument>proxy-standard</argument>
                       <argument>-filepath</argument>
                       <argument>proxy-service/target/lib</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <classpathScope>run</classpathScope>
                    <includePluginDependencies>true</includePluginDependencies>
                 </configuration>
                 <goals>
                    <goal>exec</goal>
                 </goals>
              </execution>
           </executions>
        <dependencies>
           <dependency>
              <groupId>com.veracode.vosp.api.wrappers</groupId>
              <artifactId>vosp-api-wrappers-java</artifactId>
              <version>20.7.7.0</version>
           </dependency>
        </dependencies>
     </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting the skip parameter to strue in all child poms.

[description of skip](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html#skip)